# Covariate for consistent estimation of treatment effect

Tags: experiment-design, treatment-effect

I come across this sentence as I was reading journals: "to consistently estimate the treatment eﬀect, any covariate X introduced must have equal expectations in treatment and control: E[X|Di= 1] = E[X|Di= 0]."

Could someone help me mathematically show why this is true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This requirement is generally used to justify the use of a difference in means of the outcome across treatment groups (i.e., $E[Y|D=1]-E[Y|D=0]$) as a consistent estimate of the causal effect of $D$ on $Y$. This requirement is sufficient only when the structural (i.e., causal, data-generating) model for the outcome linearly depends on the covariates and treatment. Consider the following structural model for the outcome:
$$Y = \beta_0 + \tau D + \beta_1 X + \varepsilon$$
where $\varepsilon$ is uncorrelated with $X$.
If $X$ is not caused by $D$, then $\tau$ represents the total causal effect of $D$ on $Y$ as measured by the difference in means of $Y$. The matter in question is when the difference in outcome means across the treatment groups (i.e., $E[Y|D=1]-E[Y|D=0]$) is equal to $\tau$. We can figure this out by expanding the difference in outcome means using the structural model for the outcome, as follows:
\begin{aligned}
E[Y|D=1]-E[Y|D=0] &=(\beta_0 + \tau + \beta_1E[X|D=1]) - (\beta_0 + \beta_1E[X|D=0]) \\ &= \tau + \beta_1(E[X|D=1] - E[X|D=0])
\end{aligned}
When $E[X|D=1] - E[X|D=0] = 0$, i.e., when $E[X|D=1] = E[X|D=0]$, then the second term in the last line drops to $0$, and we see that $E[Y|D=1]-E[Y|D=0] = \tau$. So, in this case, when the difference in covariate means across treatment groups is zero, the difference in outcome means across tretaments groups is equal to the causal effect of the treatment on the outcome. When multiple covariates are part of the data-genertaing process, it works the same; the difference in means for all covariates must be zero for the difference in outcome means to be equal to the causal effect.

This fact is why randomized experiments are so important for estimating causal effects; regardless of the form of the structural model for the outcome, successful randomization without dropout ensures that (in expectation, i.e., in large samples and across multiple experiments), the differences in covariate means across treatment groups will be zero, even if the covariates are not observed. This is also why matching methods are popular for observational studies (i.e., when randomization is impossible); matching allows you to create a sample in which the covariate means are the same across treatment groups (if done successfully), though matching can only help to balance observed covariates and not unobserved covariates.

Note that the result above only applies when the outcome is a linear function of the treatment and covariates. If it is a nonlinear function (e.g., a logistic regression for a binary outcome) or if there are treatment-covariate interactions in the structural model for the outcome, then there are additional requirements for the difference in outcomes means to be equal to the causal effect of the treatment.

Comment: This is as complete and clear as I would have hoped for. Thanks you Noah. Could you briefly explain (or point me to the right resources/references) what the "additional requirements" are for the two cases you have mentioned (i.e. binary outcome case and if you want interactions), as both are very practical and common I think that we should know. Thank you very much sir!!!

Comment: Glas this was helpful. There isn't a good paper out there that I have found that explains it succinctly, which is why I am writing one :) A thorough account is given by [Sauppe & Jacobson (2017)](https://doi.org/10.1002/nav.21751). With $X$-$D$ interactions in the true outcome model, you need $E[X|D=0]=E[X|D=1]=E[X]$, which is a bit stronger (sometimes called 3-way balance).